# After updating to Ubuntu 12.0.4, screen does not work if switched on after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, grub

We install base images onto our machines to ensure the setup is the same for each of them. Recently, we updated the base image to use Ubuntu 12.0.4 instead of Ubuntu 9.04.

We have this weird issue where, if we switch plug in a screen on after switching on the machine, then the screen simply goes into sleep mode - as if it has not been plugged in at all. Restarting the machine works. Could I perhaps change the Xorg.conf file or grub settings to fix this problem? It did not use to do this in the old base image containing version 9.04.

Comment: Ok it seems I lied. The Ubuntu 9.04 version one behaves the same.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so to solve this issue one needs to edit the /etc/default/grub file.

In the 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT' line, include the argument 'video=VGA-1:e' without the quotations. This  tells the kernel to enable VGA-1 regardless of whether or not it detects is screen there.